# Paypal Pro Hosted GetTransactionDetails 10002 error

Tags: paypal

I'm having a nightmare setting up and testing the Paypal Pro hosted solution.

I'm using a french Paypal pro test account, as that's the only one that seems to work in sandbox, but can't get the GetTransactionDetails api to work.

I've set-up the api credentials in the French test account, here's an example of a request and response (I assume the transaction id is the tx=xxxx part of the url when I'm returned to my site after making a payment):

Request:

```
METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&

VERSION=61.0&

PWD=7696QBU7L3SUYMWT&

USER=pro_1287586586_biz_api1.c2clearcreative.co.uk&

SIGNATURE=AZM7qyLQwGJWoFkHbU-9kOpoRAKJAIqby-nxAv-RpPwdcTpWS6v67SeO&

TRANSACTIONID=48K385189F726971V
```

Response:

```
Array (

[TIMESTAMP] => 2011%2d09%2d01T13%3a47%3a03Z

[CORRELATIONID] => 8c86184720e0

[ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 61%2e0

[BUILD] => 2089897

[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002

[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error

[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid

[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

)
```

10002 is a very general error that seems to imply API authorisation problem.

I've checked and double checked the api credentials.

Does anyone know of other things I can try to get this working?

Many thanks for any advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 10002 error only means 1 of 2 things.

1. Your API credentials are invalid (extra spaces in any field make it invalid)
2. You're sending the request to the wrong server (where the API username you're submitting does not exist)

   - Check your API Username, Password, and Signature for leading/trailing spaces
   - Check that your shopping cart does not have 'test mode' on, or 'development mode' or anything like that. It should be sending the API requests to .paypal.com if you're using live credentials. (.sandbox.paypal.com if you're using sandbox credentials)

[Successful API call here](https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&VERSION=61.0&PWD=7696QBU7L3SUYMWT&USER=pro_1287586586_biz_api1.c2clearcreative.co.uk&SIGNATURE=AZM7qyLQwGJWoFkHbU-9kOpoRAKJAIqby-nxAv-RpPwdcTpWS6v67SeO&TRANSACTIONID=48K385189F726971V) Even though you're trying to get information about a transaction that isn't on that sandbox account.

Comment: I was using the wrong Endpoint!! Thanks for point out the obvious to me, it's much appreciated. In case anyone else has trouble knowing which Endpoint to use it's all here: [link](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_endpoints)

Comment: Thank you for the successful call example. I was using `PASSWORD` instead of `PWD` and was missing the version variable.

Comment: @Jeshurun, not using PWD would definitely do it. The Version variable missing throws a different error.

Comment: Yep, I remember getting the other one when I fixed the `PWD` variable.